# How to convert base64 byte data into downloadable pdf file?

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I have an encoded base64 data from an API response and stored in a variable encodedBase64.

let encodedBase64 = 'some base64 encoded long data';

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    console.log('binaryString ', binaryString);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
       var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
       bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
 }

 function saveByteArray(reportName, byte) {
    var blob = new Blob([byte], {type: "application/pdf"});
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = reportName;
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
};

var sampleArr = base64ToArrayBuffer(encodedBase64);
saveByteArray("Sample Report", sampleArr);
```

after executing this code i am able to download pdf file names `SampleReport.pdf` but when i open this it is showing `Failed to load PDF document.` error
what is the wrong in my code ?

Comment: Can't see nothing wrong in the code.* Are you sure the data in `encodedBase64` is valid? Can you open the pdf by prepending `"data:application/pdf;base64,"` to it and setting the resulting string as your browser's URL? (* well in Firefox you would need to append that <a> in the document so its `click` works, but that's clearly not linked to the issue you describe).

Comment: data:application/pdf;base64 -- yes after setting it into browser URL also it is showing the same error, Failed to load PDF document

Comment: Then your base64 data is corrupted.

Comment: but i tried to decode it online and downloaded pdf file but that pdf file downloaded was not corrupted.

Comment: have you tried using saveByteArray("Sample Report", encodedBase64 );

Comment: yes, even that is also not working

Comment: Could you link to that base64 data? Maybe as a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). [Your code works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/9sxm7qrv/).

Comment: Your code works fine for me! and obviously your code saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

difficult to get it done using front end side

but it can be done easily using Nodejs using the following code.

```
fs.writeFile('pdfFileName.pdf', base64DataString, {encoding: 'base64'}, error => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('buffer saved!');
    }
});
```